# Imacros loop and change proxy?

Tags: loops, firefox, proxy, imacros

I want to make script imacros to set datasoruce ts.txt and I add 100 entry column1

I want to set loop to column 1, and after finish imacros clear cookies and change proxy?

```
VERSION BUILD=9052613
TAB T=1
FILTER TYPE=IMAGES STATUS=ON
SET !DATASOURCE xxx.txt
URL GOTO=http://
wait seconds=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/ ATTR=NAME:xxxx CONTENT={{!COL1}}
wait seconds=3``
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ ATTR=ID:submit
wait seconds=3
CLEAR
```

change proxy
loop

Comment: Try to explain it better, I can't understand a thing

Answer (score 2):

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !DATASOURCE **proxies.csv**

SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2

SET !LOOP 1

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

SET !TIMEOUT 60

CLEAR


'proxy module

URL GOTO=about:config

URL GOTO=javascript:var<SP>prefb<SP>=<SP>Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);var<SP>str<SP>=<SP>Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);str.data<SP>=<SP>"{{!COL1}}";prefb.setComplexValue("network.proxy.http",<SP>Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString,<SP>str);

URL GOTO=about:config

URL GOTO=javascript:gPrefBranch.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port",{{!COL2}});
```